# Running forever within su as a different user

Tags: node.js, bash, su, forever

I am experiencing weird behavior with forever, which I want to use to keep alive my node app.

I want to run my forever processes as my regular user `lwood`, not as `root`.

I need to know how to run forever properly within `root` mode, but **as the user `lwood`**. (This is needed because, for example as a special case, upstart scripts run as root.)

These commands illustrate my problem (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, and `$` is regular user and `#` is root):

```
$ su
[type in su password]

# cd /home/lwood/myapp
# sudo -u lwood forever -a -l "/home/lwood/myapp/logfile.log" start app.js
info:    Forever processing file: app.js

# forever list    
info:    No forever processes running

# exit

$ forever list
info:    No forever processes running
```

So forever successfully started, yet no processes are running under neither lwood nor root!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In your other comment you said the app is not running.  What's in your forever log files?  Where is it crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using upstart, try this (putting it to your upstart script)

exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /usr/local/bin/forever ...

reference: https://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users

Answer (score 1):

On systems with systemd (RHEL 7, CentOS 7, Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, ...) you can use this script as /usr/lib/systemd/system/nodejs.service or equivalent (check for other *.service files):

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Application
After=postgresql.service network.target
Wants=postgresql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/su - <user> -c '/usr/bin/npm start --prefix /path/to/app'
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/app
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's running as a different context on a different user. Maybe you need to add sudo a swell for the list:

```
sudo -u lwood forever list
```

Comment: 1) As shown in my question, I already ran "forever list" as both users without success. 2) If I run your command within # (root mode), I get an exception "TypeError: Object Error: EACCES, permission denied '/root/.forever/sock'" That makes sense because I'm trying to list the **root's** processes as **lwood**. 3) An easy way in which I can see if my app is running is to refresh my browser. The app is indeed not running :) Any further ideas?